# Sorting on timestamp, but grouping by another field

Tags: oracle

I have a bit of a complex query I am trying to write that will eventually be used in a web application. I am pulling a value for stack, lot of parts, and then a count of discs in that lot and the oldest timestamp value.  I have a group by for stack, lot that allows me to figure out the num of discs from that lot in that stack.

What I want to do is get it so that the stacks are grouped together with the oldest stack on top.

This is an example of how it looks now:

```
STACK     LOT     COUNT(CONTAINER_ID)     MIN(TIMESTAMP)
-----     ---     ---------               --------------
001       4       3                       8/30/2015 9:47:10
002       3       6                       8/30/2015 12:22:03
001       2       10                      8/31/2015 9:47:10
```

I want it to look more like this:

```
STACK     LOT     COUNT(CONTAINER_ID)     MIN(TIMESTAMP)
-----     ---     ---------               --------------
001       4       3                      8/30/2015 9:47:10
001       2       10                     8/31/2015 9:47:10
002       3       6                      8/30/2015 12:22:03
```

Those are just short examples of the tables I are about 20 different stack IDs and probably 3 or 4 lots in each stack.

I tried partition by, but when I looked into it a bit more I am not sure if that was what I actually wanted to use.

```
SELECT STACK, LOT, COUNT(CONTAINER_ID), MIN(TIMESTAMP) 
FROM PAINT_TABLE 
GROUP BY STACK, LOT 
ORDER BY MIN(TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: Did you try ordering by MIN(TIMESTAMP)?

Comment: @DavidAldridge Sorry forgot to put that in my simplified select statement. Yea and that will sort all of the values in order. But I want to keep all of the rows of the same stack together.

Comment: Do you mind providing a query that matches your sample structure and data?

Comment: I think that analytic function is what you need here, to get the min timestamp for all occurrences of the stack, and then it can be ordered by that in an outer query. I shall send a fellow along to write that up ...

Comment: @sstan is that better? I used the terms that are in my DB for the statement, but more defined names in the table for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of a mismatch between your sample structure + data, and the query.

But the general idea is that you can get what you are looking for by using an analytic function in your `order by` clause.  Something like this:

```
select *
from paint_table
order by min(timestamp) over (partition by stack), stack
```

**EDIT**

If the idea is that you want the `min(timestamp)` to be determined by `stack` and then have the ordering based on that, but at the same time you want to group by both `stack` and `lot`, then you can do this:

```
select stack, lot, count(container_id), min_stack_timestamp
  from (select t.*,
               min(t.timestamp) over (partition by t.stack) as min_stack_timestamp
          from paint_table t)
 group by min_stack_timestamp, stack, lot
 order by min_stack_timestamp, stack, lot
```

Comment: I think this is what I needed. Going to test it a bit more to make sure. Thanks!

Comment: I added an edit that I think will get you closer (if I understand the intent of your query).